# Showing a specific graphic onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I currently have a piece of JavaScript that takes the value and the selected text from the PHP dynamic dropdown menu and passes it through to a input box for editing.

**Questions:**

How could I pass a PHP item through the JavaScript to show the specific image for the selected value when it is selected?

How could I make the selected text echo into the input box on select?

```
 $('#captionSelect').change(function(){
                    $('#captionInput').val($("#captionSelect option:selected").html()).show();
                });

<select name="captionSelect" id="captionSelect">
    <?php foreach ($get_images as $image){
        echo '<option value="'.$image['id'].'">'.$image['description'].'</option>';
    };
    ?>
    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="captionSelect" id="captionSelect">
    <?php
        foreach ($get_images as $image){
            echo '<option title="'.$image['thumbname'].'" value="'.$image['id'].'" id="captionOption_'.$image['id'].'">'.$image['description'].'</option>';
        };
    ?>
</select>
<input id="captionInput" type="text" />
<img id="preview" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#captionSelect').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var caption = $('#captionOption_' + id).html();
        var thumbname = $('#captionOption_' + id).attr('title');
        $('#captionInput').val(caption);
        $('#preview').attr('src', '/path/to/pictures/' + thumbname + '.jpg');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would I need to implement a hidden field as I need to use .$image['thumbname']. to get the image name?

Comment: Thank you :)  I have implemented your code and changed this line to '/includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/' + thumbname); the title is showing correct but I am still not seeing an image.  Is there anyway that I can set my base_url in the js?

Comment: Could I get a link to your web page?

Comment: No sorry as it is a live site,  I just cant see the image when I select the item from the select drop down menu.  When I try and update it also does not show the text in the input box ether

Comment: I changed the code so the **<input />** value is changed. But I can't just guess what the problem is about the picture; have you checked if the calculated path is correct? Maybe use some **alert()** for debugging.

Comment: I have just looked over my page in firebug and it has that there is a syntax error with var id = $(this).val();

Comment: Okay, this is it. Bugproof, cross-browser, and tested.

Comment: Thank you,  Could you do me an example how I could do an alert that would show the file path?

Comment: Come on... **alert('/path/to/pictures/' + thumbname + '.jpg');** (put this at the end of the function called when the <select> is changed)